# Use \acs inside \DeclareMathOperator with bold font

Tags: bold, math-operators, acronyms

I want to use the an acronym defined with the `acronym` package inside the definition of a math operator. The math operator should appear in bold font. However, this does not work as the `\acs` command does not care about the surrounding `\mathbf` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}

\DeclareMathOperator{\df}{\mathbf{\acs{DF}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dfnoacs}{\mathbf{DF}} % how it should look like

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{DF}{discount factor}
\end{acronym}

\begin{align*}
\df(...) &= ... \\
\dfnoacs(...) &= ...
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

IMO, the usage of another argument to `\acs` like `\acs{DF}{...}{discount factor}` is not option as I do not want to use another style in the list of acronyms.

Comment: I don't think that the first appearance of the acronym in a math formula would make much sense.

Comment: @egreg I agree but the question is not about the first appearance of an acronym, it's about reusing the definition of the acronym. Consider I want to switch the representation from "DF" to "df" (lowercase) then I don't want to change my entire latex document and search up the places where I wrote "DF". It's better to use the generic acronym macro.

Comment: If you define `\DeclareMathOperator{\df}{\mathbf{DF}}`, then just changing `DF` into `df` would do the same as you ask for.

Comment: Well, but if I use `\DeclareMathOperator{\df}{\mathbf{DF}}` in math mode and `\acs{DF}` in text mode, there are still two places to change it. However, there are indeed math operator names that I don't want to introduce but put the name in the list of acronyms, so the first appearance is in the math operator (it's more like nomenclature).

Comment: Acronyms and math operators are very different things, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `\textbf` instead of `\mathbf`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}

\DeclareMathOperator{\df}{\textbf{\acs{DF}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dfnoacs}{\mathbf{DF}} % how it should look like

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{DF}{discount factor}
\end{acronym}

\begin{align*}
\df(\dots) &= \dots \\
\dfnoacs(\dots) &= \dots
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

However using the sans serif family too via

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\df}{\textbf{\sffamily\acs{DF}}}
```

will better match the appearance in text:

[image: text version]

[image: new math version]